# How can I specify the icon for a new wizard in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've added a custom new project wizard to Eclipse which uses the preexisting Java nature.  Here's the block from plugin.xml where I add it:

```
  <wizard
        class="com.corp.eclipse.wizard.project.NewExtensionWizard"
        descriptionImage="/rsrc/icons/app.png"
        finalPerspective="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective"
        icon="rsrc/icons/app.png"
        id="framer.newExtensionWizard"
        name="Extension Project"
        project="true">
  </wizard>
```

The "Extension Project" project type shows up just fine in the "New" dialog, but the icon is not displayed.  Does anyone know if there's a trick to getting icons attached to wizards in Eclipse?  This is Eclipse 3.5.2.

Comment: Are you sure the "rsrc/icons/app.png" is the relative path of plugin.xml?

Comment: Or you miss the rsrc/ folder in your build.properties?

Comment: Nope, rsrc/ is in build.properties.  I'm sure the path to the icon is correct, since the icon shows up in wizard Eclipse gives you for editing plugin.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as yours and I had to breakpoint through the initialisation code to finally find out why. This may be your issue:

In `AbstractUIPlugin.class`, `imageDescriptorFromPlugin(...)`

```
// if the bundle is not ready then there is no image
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
if (!BundleUtility.isReady(bundle)) {
    return null;
}
```

The bundle may not be loading. This can happen if the id of the plugin is not a prefix of the extension point (as was my case). So, the id for your wizard is `framer.newExtensionWizard`. Unless your entire plugin id (Bundle-SymbolicName in MANIFEST.MF) is just `framer`, the method is not going to find the bundle, and thus the image will not appear.

The solution then is to make sure that whatever id you give your plugin, make sure all extension point ids use that id as a prefix.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly specific!  Unfortunately, I don't work at the company where I had this problem, so the code is lost to me (and I don't use Eclipse anymore).  I'll accept it anyhow, so you get credit for weighing in helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

Is rsrc is your source folder? Usually icons folder is kept under the project directly. You can move it out of the source folder and also specify it in the build.properties.

Comment: Nope, it's a child of the project folder, next to the source folder.  This is the convention for projects at my company.

Comment: Is your icon in the right size? Can you try a gif file instead of png?

Comment: I'm not the original poster, but I can confirm I have the same issue in Indigo, whether the icon is .png or .gif. The very same icon works fine for org.eclipse.ui.editors, so I know it can see and display the icon. It just doesn't show with org.eclipse.ui.newWizards.